# Silverlight won't display xaml page element or grid resources

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I made the following XAML file using XSLT. When I open the XAML file in KaXaml it shows exactly what I would expect it to show. When I incorporate it in a Visual Studio project it displays the same thing in the visual editor. When I try to run the page, it won't load. If I delete the `Page` element and the `Grid.Resources` element, it runs without any problem, but obviously all of the formatting is gone.

Is there an easy way to make this work? Should I use alternatives to `Page` and `Grid.Resources`?

For some reason or other I can't copy/paste the code here, I've put it up on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xMnyPDqc)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason to use Page?

If you use a `UserControl` root, it works fine.

And, comment out this line:

```
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#556B2F"/>
```

In the `TextBlock` Style, since that property is not supported.

Comment: No, no reason I'm using `Page`, I'm just very new to this. I replaced the `Page` element with `UserControl` but it still won't show up for me.

Comment: I'm using the `UserControl` and I deleted the `Background` Setter, but it still won't work for me.